# Solving equation for Complex conjugate

Tags: equation-solving, complex

How to solve the equation like this:

$-par-(x+yi)-a\overline{r}=0 $ where $p,a,x,y$ are constant real numbers, $r$ is complex number and $\overline{r}$ is its complex conjugate. I want to solve for $r$

I tried to use Assumptions on $p,a,x,y$ so that they are real and tried to solve it, but I get a very weird solution, i.e

Assumptions = {{a,p} [Element] Reals}
Solve[-r a p - (x+yI) - a r[Conjugate] == 0 ,r]

which is different from the answer in the book. Any guidance for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
ClearAll[r, a, p, x, y];
ComplexExpand@Solve[-r a p - (x + y*I) - a *Conjugate[r] == 0, r]
```

[image]

> which is different from the answer in the book.

What is the book answer?

Also in Mathematica be careful with space. `yI` is not the same as `y*I`.

Also You can use `ComplexExpand` instead of assuming variables are real.

Comment: Yes! this is the answer. What is meant by ClearAll anyway?

Comment: @Nothing it is always good idea to clear variables before using them.